# Mapbasic write and read csv into python tuple type structure

Tags: mapbasic, array

In mapbasic I need to read a csv into an array but arrange each row of the csv independently.

See the current result, code etc below.

I want it to be something like a python dictionary

```
([Bushfire_V Char (1) ;,Bushfire_V, Bushfire Hazard - Very High,    Bushfire_Hazard,OVL2_CAT,BHR_VPI], [Agri_Ovela Char (1) ;,  Agri_Ovela, Agricultural Land Class,Agricultural_Land_Classification_Class_A_and_B, OVL_CAT,NR])
```

Later on I need to pass some of these to other subroutines to run a process.

For example I need

```
planning_tab="Bushfire_Hazard"+".tab"
planning_layer="Bushfire_V"
planning_attrib="OVL2_CAT"
planning_val="BHR_VPI"
```

then on the next run

```
planning_tab="Agricultural_Land_Classification_Class_A_and_B"+."tab"
planning_layer="Agri_Ovela"
planning_attrib="OVL_CAT"
planning_val="NR"
```

Input CSV
[image]

Code base

```
Call ReadTextFileToArray(txtFile, myArray) '// populate array
For i = 1 to UBound(myArray)
 Print i+", "+myArray(i)
 Next    '// go to next element in array
Sub ReadTextFileToArray(ByVal txtFilePath as String, myArray() as String)

Dim i as Integer

    i = 1

    Open file txtFilePath for input as #1   '// open text file for input (to read) as #1
    Do Until EOF(1)             '// do until the end of file #1 is reached
        Redim myArray(i)        '// resize array to i
        Input #1, myArray(i)    '// read value from text file
        i = i + 1               '// increment i
    Loop                        '// return to Do Until...

End Sub
```

Result

```
1, Column
2, Cleaned
3, Friendly_Name
4, Related_Tab
5, Tab_Column
6, Value
7, Bushfire_V Char (1) ;
8, Bushfire_V
9, Bushfire Hazard - Very High
10, Bushfire_Hazard
11, OVL2_CAT
12, BHR_VPI
13, Bushfire_M Char (1) ;
14, Bushfire_M
15, Bushfire Hazard - Medium
16, Bushfire_Hazard
17, OVL2_CAT
18, BHR_MPI
19, Bushfire_H Char (1) ;
20, Bushfire_H
21, Bushfire Hazard - High
22, Bushfire_Hazard
23, OVL2_CAT
24, BHR_HPI
25, Acid_Low Char (1) ;
26, Acid_Low
27, Acid Sulfate Soil - Low Probability
28, Low_Probability_of_Acid_Sulfate_Soils
29, OVL2_CAT
30, PAS_A20
31, Acid_High Char (1) ;
32, Acid_High
33, Acid Sulfate Soil - High Probability
34, High_Probability_of_Acid_Sulfate_Soils
35, OVL2_CAT
36, PAS_A05
37, Agri_Ovela Char (1) ;
38, Agri_Ovela
39, Agricultural Land Class
40, Agricultural_Land_Classification_Class_A_and_B
41, OVL_CAT
42, NR
43,
```

How do I write it into an array, tuple (or whatever Mapbasic calls it) and read from it a row at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not open the CSV into a MapInfo table? Then you could easily read the data from the mapinfo table to achieve the output you want. Take a look at the `Register Table` command in the reference guide for details on how to do this.

Comment: Once I register the table as a tab file, I can't find any reference on how to read it line by line and just get the columns of a row that I need to use in the SQL queries.

Comment: Accepted as I found TABLEINFO() and SEARCH_INFO_ROW